# Filling spaces between polygons using ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: arcgis-pro, topology, slivers

I have a polygon with 4 attributes (1,2,3 or 4).  In the process of creating this polygon (merge/erase/union), there were gaps left between 1 and 2,  with some of the gaps having slivers of 3 or 4.

How do I snap polygon 1 to polygon 2,  without moving polygon 2, and simultaneously remove any slivers 3 and 4, using ArcGIS Pro?

Comment: I have reduced the scope of your question to ArcGIS Pro so if you also want to ask about ArcGIS Desktop 10.6 then that can be done in a separate question. The answer to one may or may not be the same as for the other.

Comment: I think your question would benefit from a picture of the input and desired output for a few polygons.

Comment: I think this would take a bit of coding, are you looking for code that does this?

Answer (score 3):

Check out the [Integrate tool](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/integrate.htm) it will make features coincident if they are within a specified distance:

> Maintains the integrity of shared feature boundaries by making
>   features coincident if they fall within the specified x,y tolerance.
>   Features that fall within the specified x,y tolerance are considered
>   identical or coincident.

Comment: It does make them coincident, but both polygons move.

Answer (score 0):

https://community.esri.com/thread/84156

or

https://community.esri.com/ideas/14906-pro-holes-in-polygons-like-arc

discuss a similar problem, and have additional links to the help topic that may work for you.